# How can I give my GitHub repository multiple coloured-circle "technology badges"?

Tags: github, repository, programming-languages

I have added a repository to GitHub with the following **5 files**:

- `README.md`
- `my-php-file-1.php`
- `my-javascript-file-1.js`
- `my-php-file-2.php`
- `my-javascript-file-2.js`

Under **Manage Topics** I have indicated that the repository should include the topics:

- `PHP`
- `Javascript`

Nevertheless, on my **Overview** and **Repositories** pages, this repository only ever shows up with a badge featuring a small coloured circle and `PHP`.

---

This appears to be normal behaviour. I note that *all* my repositories are the same - they only ever have a single badge attached - even when they feature three, four or five technologies.

I have searched the web repeatedly but I'm none the wiser - how do I give the repository above a `Javascript` badge, alongside its `PHP` badge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coloured circle you see does not list technologies used, it shows the [repository language](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-repository-languages). This is usually the language that has the most code in your repository, and only one language will be visible.

The language is determined by the [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist), and you have the option of [fixing it if it is detected incorrectly](https://github.com/github/linguist#troubleshooting) or [overriding defaults](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) (e.g. ignoring certain files, such as data files), if necessary.

Comment: Aha. Does that mean I should never expect any repository to have more than one badge?